# read file of different format efficiently in r

Tags: r

I have following format of file

```
*NEWRECORD
MH = Public Service Announcements as Topic
AQ = CL EC ES HI LJ SN ST TD UT
MN = L01.143.805
UI = D066308

*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Public Service Announcements
MN = V02.736
MH_TH = NLM (2016)
ST = T170
DA = 20150701
```

basically I have above content in my file. My aim is to get MH and MN values. The file is big, and mainly in above format.

Comment: I would look for a solution using sed or awk to pre-process the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will Something like this work?

```
d <- readLines('mydata.txt') # Read in data
out <- strsplit(d[grep(pattern = "MH|MN", x = d)], ' = ') #Look for those lines
do.call(rbind, out) # Bind it together
```

If you want to indicate which record it came from you might need to add an id column before binding it together.